# Question on the Derivative of a Fourier transform

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis

> Let
>   $$
> \mathcal{F}(w) = \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{-iwx}g(x)d\mu(x), \quad w\in \mathbb{R}.
> $$ 
>   I want to show that the $n$-th derivative is given by
>   $$
> \mathcal{F}^{(n)}(w) =  i^n\int_{\mathbb{R}}(-x)^ne^{-iwx}g(x)d\mu(x).
> $$

So I started with first derivative.

I want to show that
$$
\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{\mathcal{F}(w+h)-\mathcal{F}(w)}{h} +i\int_{\mathbb{R}}xe^{-iwx}g(x)d\mu(x)= 0.
$$

I did a bunch of expansions and I got $$\lim_{h} \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{h}+ix\right)e^{-iwx}g(x)d\mu(x)$$ but I cant really think of what to do form here. I thought of using the Holders inequality and the fact that $e^z = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^k}{k!}$ but its not helping. Any hints?

Comment: Doesn't this follow from the Leibniz integral rule?  Or are you not assuming that to be true?

Comment: I am assuming that to not be true. @MichaelSeifert

Comment: What you can do here is use the fact that $\frac{e^{-ixh}-1}{h}$ is very close to $-ix$ when $|x| < \epsilon/h$, and is bounded otherwise.  Then by splitting up the integral into a region "near" 0 and its complement you can find the limit.  For this to work however you need $\int |x g(x)| < \infty$ (the conclusion doesn't make much sense otherwise anyway).

Comment: To what space does $g$ belong here?

Comment: Differentiation of parameter dependent integrals!